# How common are semiprimes with equally bitsized factors among semiprimes with equal bitsize?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, prime-numbers, computational-number-theory

I am curious about the following after having looked at the paper "[Almost primes in almost all short intervals](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.06005.pdf)", theorem 3 says:

> Almost all intervals $[x, x + \log^{3.51}{(x)}]$ with $x ≤ X$ contain
> a product of exactly two distinct primes.

First, let $|\cdot|_2$ denote the bitsize of a number.

This result lead me as follows: For a fixed $m$ and any semiprime $n=pq$ such that $|n|_2=m$, what is the probability that $|p|_2=|q|_2$?

Or, similarly, for a given $x$ how far would we have to walk up the number line to guarantee that we will find such an $n$? That is: for what function $f(x)$ can we guarantee that the interval $[x, x + f(x)]$ contains such an $n$?

**Edit 1:** The bitsize of a number is the number of digits in the binary representation of a number. In particular, this is how computers represent numbers in hardware. For example, the bitsize of $33$ is $6$ because $33 = (100001)_2$ in base $2$.

Comment: What is the bitsize of a number?

Comment: @JoshuaStucky I added this clarification as an edit.

Comment: The formula $\lceil \log_2 x\rceil$ is perhaps an easier way to describe the bitsize of a number, although generally people don't bother with the $\lceil \cdot \rceil$.

Comment: That being said, the answer appears to be not that common, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586010/relative-size-of-most-factors-of-semiprimes-close)